# Table won´t center R markdown latex

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I've tried many things, but it won't work.
Here is my table, and my attempt:

```
\center

|  Período  | IIX_3\_1 | IIX_2\_1 | IIX_1\_2 | IIX_1\_1 |
|:---------:|:--------:|:--------:|:--------:|:--------:|
| 1986-2002 | -0,47066 | -0,49753 | -0,41377 | -0,45399 |
| 2002-2021 | 0,718474 | 0,71391  | -0,32246 | 0,022513 |
| 1986-2021 | 0,750236 | 0,714512 | -0,05268 | 0,387423 |

: Tabla de correlación de Pearson

\justify
```

[image: result]

I also tried with `<center></center>` but didn't work.
Just in case, I post the YAML:

```
---
geometry: margin=3.5cm

output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: TRUE
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{sectsty,ragged2e,fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
  - \allsectionsfont{\color{cyan}}
  - \usepackage{floatrow}
  - \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}    
fontsize: 11pt
sansfont: Georgia
---
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look on `knitr::kable()` function or `kableExtra` package.

Comment: This is a LaTeX problem, not r-markdown.  If you take out   `- \usepackage{floatrow}
  - \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}` from your YAML the table ends up centered.  You could ask on tex.stackexchange.com if there's a way to do this if you really need floatrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that normally `floatrow` has to be loaded before `longtable`, but as rmakrdown interferes with your ability to load the packages in the correct order, you can use the following workaround:

```
---
geometry: margin=3.5cm

output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: TRUE
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{sectsty,ragged2e,fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
  - \allsectionsfont{\color{cyan}}
  - \usepackage{floatrow}
  - \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}    
  -  \setlength\LTleft\fill
  - \setlength\LTright\fill
fontsize: 11pt
sansfont: Georgia
---


|  Período  | IIX_3\_1 | IIX_2\_1 | IIX_1\_2 | IIX_1\_1 |
|:---------:|:--------:|:--------:|:--------:|:--------:|
| 1986-2002 | -0,47066 | -0,49753 | -0,41377 | -0,45399 |
| 2002-2021 | 0,718474 | 0,71391  | -0,32246 | 0,022513 |
| 1986-2021 | 0,750236 | 0,714512 | -0,05268 | 0,387423 |

: Tabla de correlación de Pearson

\justifying


long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text
```

[image]